# django: admin site not formatted

Tags: python, django, django-admin, gunicorn

I have a mostly entirely plain django project, with no adding of my own media or customization of the admin interface in any way. Running the server with `python manage.py runserver` results in a nicely-formatted admin interface. Running the server with `gunicorn_django` does not. Why is this the case, and how can I fix it?

It's definitely an issue of not finding the `css` files, but where are they stored? I never configured this, and the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting is `''`.

EDIT: I just want to know how django-admin serves the non-existent admin files... and how can I get gunicorn_django to do the same?

Comment: why the downvote? should i put on serverfault instead perhaps? i'm hardly an administrator, this is just my project. superuser? this seems out of place there

Comment: Identical to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032519/why-cant-django-find-my-admin-media-files-once-i-leave-the-built-in-runserver

Comment: I think it was downvoted because it's a very basic question that sort-of borders on RTFM. It is a problem that people face but Django documentation and tutorials are pretty explicit on this topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: @Jordan: i see your point. my confusion was that i don't have any static files, i never set it up at all, i never got involved, so i just had no idea where to look.

Comment: i just want to know how django-admin serves the non-existent admin files... and how can i get gunicorn_django to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you use contrib.static, you have to execute a `collectstatic` command to get all the app-specific static files (including admin's own) into the public directory that is served by gunicorn.

Comment: i have django 1.2... where can i just get the django admin static files?

Comment: Open the shell, load any django package and print its `__file__` property, it will show the actual path where the files are. Look into there and symlink into the served media.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem too (because I do some development against gunicorn), and here's how to remove the admin-media magic and serve admin media like any other media through urls.py:

```
import os

import django

...

admin_media_url = settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX.lstrip('/') + '(?P<path>.*)$'
admin_media_path = os.path.join(django.__path__[0], 'contrib', 'admin', 'media')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^' + admin_media_url , 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': admin_media_path,
    }, name='admin-media'),
    ...
)
```

Also: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2547/

And, of course, `#include <production_disclaimer.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to add alias to nginx (are you using one?!) configuration file:

```
location /static/admin/ {
    alias /<path_to_your_admin_static_files>/;
}
```

it worked immediately for me

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. Just had to add this line to `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/claudiu/server/.virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/'
```

Comment: With this solution you are not going to serve anything else than admin media... The approach recommended in the django 1.2 docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2//howto/deployment/modpython/#serving-the-admin-files) is to link the admin media into the document root as served by your server. In your case it's setting `MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/media'` and symlinking `...django/contrib/admin/media/admin` into there

Comment: @saverio: how would i distinguish between admin media and my media? wouldn't it look like `/var/media/admin` if i make a symlink, and if media_root is `/var/media`, it won't find them?

Comment: Admin media is served from `/var/media/admin`, the rest from the root `/var/media`. If you use the django auth app as media root you lose the ability to serve other media.

Answer (score 0):

David Wolever's answer was close, for my installation, but I think some paths may have changed in newer django. In particular I set

```
admin_media_path = os.path.join(django.__path__[0], 'contrib', 'admin', 'static', 'admin')
```

and in urlpatterns added:

```
url(r'^static/admin/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': admin_media_path,
    }),
```

based on info found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

works for me, but more "magical" than I like.